# Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'image' cannot be null

Tags: laravel

I am confused about this error guys. I have no idea what is wrong here.

edit.blade:

```
<input type="file" name="image" class="form-control" placeholder="image">
```

Controller:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $sales = sales::find($id);

    $request->validate([
        'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
    ]);

    if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
        $destination_path = 'public/imagen/shop_logo';
        $image = $request->file('image');
        $image_name = $image->getClientOriginalName();
        $path = $request->file('image')->storeAs($destination_path, $image_name);

        $input['image']=$image_name;
    }

    $sales->image = $request->input('image');

    $sales->save();
```

From the source code above I do not see any error there. If you guys know I need some help here

Comment: What is the type of the column `image`?

Comment: it is a string sir

Answer (score 0):

The error is what it says i.e. the image column on your sales table isn't nullable.

Then if you're inputting image in the form and you're still getting this error then make sure you've included `enctype='multipart/form-data'` in the form.

Also how can you store image directly in the db? You're supposed to store the image path in the db. Look at the following code for reference.

```
use Image;

$request->validate([
    'image' => 'required',
    'image.*' => 'mimes:jpg,jpeg,png'

]);

$path = public_path('uploads/sliders/');
if (!File::exists($path)) {
    File::makeDirectory($path, 0775, true);
}

$image = $request->file('image');
$img_name = hexdec(uniqid()).'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
Image::make($image)->resize( 847.5, 431 )->save('uploads/sliders/'.$img_name);
$image_path = 'uploads/sliders/'.$img_name;

Slider::create([
    'image' => $image_path
]);
```

Here I've used [Intervention Image library](https://image.intervention.io/v2).

Answer (score 0):

Best Practice to store images in the table

Validate your image

```php
$request->validate([
    'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
]);
```

Upload a file to a specific location

> image is the input name which will come from the Form Request and make sure you have added `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the form.

```php
$user = User::find(1);

if ( $request->hasFile('image') ) {
    // upload file
    $destination_path = 'public/images/'; // <- your path
    $image = $request->file('image');
    $image_name = $image->getClientOriginalName(); // get file name
    $path = $image->storeAs($destination_path, $image_name);

    //Save file name in the table
    $user->image = $path;
}

$user->save(); // save the modal
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign the saved path of the image to the `image` attribute of the sales object.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $sales = sales::find($id);

    $request->validate([
        'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
    ]);

    $destination_path = 'public/imagen/shop_logo';
    $image = $request->file('image');
    $image_name = $image->getClientOriginalName();
    $path = $request->file('image')->storeAs($destination_path, $image_name);

    $sales->image = $path;

    $sales->save();

    ...
}
```

---

> You may retrieve uploaded files from an `Illuminate\Http\Request` instance using the file method or using dynamic properties.

```
$file = $request->file('photo');

$file = $request->photo;
```

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/requests#retrieving-uploaded-files)

Answer (score 0):

`StoreAs()` will save the image in the storage folder so save the image path in your DB instead `$sales->image = $path;` ..also add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` as an attribute in your `<form>` tag

public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
$sales = sales::find($id);

```
    $request->validate([
        'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
    ]);

    if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
        $destination_path = 'public/imagen/shop_logo';
        $image = $request->file('image');
        $image_name = $image->getClientOriginalName();
        $path = $request->file('image')->storeAs($destination_path, $image_name);

        $input['image']=$image_name;
    }

    $sales->image = $path;

    $sales->save();
```